# Count unique elements in mutidimensional array with Jquery Mapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, chart.js

Any ideas on JQuery mapping that will return an array of duplicates names, and titles, with their count. So I can create a bar graph in D3 or Chart JS (Chart JS seems easier so far)...

ie, I have (example, using JSON)

```
 obj = {"Chocolate":"Organic", "Chocolate":"Fresh", "Chocolate":"Organic", 
    "Vanilla":"Regular", 
    "Vanilla":"Organic","Strawberry":"Fresh","Vanilla":"Regular"};
```

I want this

```
    var data = {
    labels: ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Fresh",
            fillColor: "blue",
            data: [1,0,1] //(1 Fresh chocolate, 1 Fresh Strawberry, No fresh Vanilla)
        },
        {
            label: "Regular",
            fillColor: "red",
            data: [0,0,2] //(0 regular chocolate, 0 regular Strawberry, 2 regular Vanilla)
        },
        {
            label: "Organic",
            fillColor: "green",
            data: [2,1,0] //(2 organic chocolate, 1 organic Vanilla, 0 organic strawberry)
        }
    ]
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u25c7gtj/2/

What have I tried? Well so far I have been able to group the items by Chocolate, Vanilla, or Strawberry, but the next step of getting a count of the items that have matching properties... I don't even know where to begin comparing them. I tried only pulling the "Flavor and Type", to compare those as objects but the comparison only yielded the groups with the individual flavor and type key and value pairs.

```
function groupBy(propertyName, array) {
    var groupedElements = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        var value = element[propertyName];

        var group = groupedElements[value];
        if(group == undefined) {
            group = [element];
            groupedElements[value] = group;
        } else {
            group.push(element);
        }
    }

    return groupedElements;
}

var result = groupBy("flavor", obj)
console.log(result);
$("#results").html(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

I also tried the code below which only seems to count the total

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({

    url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Ice Cream List')/items?$select=ID,Flavor,Type",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data){
       // $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
           // console.log(item.Id);
//  console.log(item.Title);
//  console.log(item.m4gs);
 //       });

var  counts = [];

jQuery.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
  if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    counts[item] = 1;
  } else {
    counts[item]++;
  }
});
console.log(counts[]);
```

Comment: `obj = {"Chocolate":"Organic", "Chocolate":"Fresh", "Chocolate":"Organic", 
    "Vanilla":"Regular", 
    "Vanilla":"Organic","Strawberry":"Fresh","Vanilla":"Regular"}` produces an object with 3 keys, each with one value - you aren't going to be able to store/represent the data this way and instead should use an array to store the variations e.g. `{ Chocolate: ['Organic', 'Fresh'], Vanilla: [] }`

Comment: Yes, that confused me when I was given this assignment, I was unsure how they were even able to use the title field with values that weren't unique. The object was pseudocode, I am returning a SharePoint List